# compatibilidad de versiones de lombok con java 17

Tags: java, spring-boot

hola gente saludos una consulta que versión de lombok es compatible con java 17, ahora estoy usando lombok 1.18.24 y no reconoce a @Data @Getter @Setter, no se exactamente si este es el problema, y si no fuera por favor alguien me puede orientar, gracias!!!

Comment: seguramente te falte instalar lomnok en tu ide. descarga el jar lo ejecutas y te saldra para instalrlo en tu ide

Comment: *"no se exactamente si este es el problema, y si no fuera por favor alguien me puede orientar"* -> Y cómo vamos a orientarte sin saber absolutamente nada del proyecto? Con la información que tengo puedo estar 100% seguro de que no has instalado lombok en el proyecto. Que lo has puesto donde no toca. Que no lo has escrito bien. Que tu proyecto ni siquiera es de Java!! Estás añadiendo la librería de lombok de java a un proyecto en C??! O en python?! Suena raro, y me extraña muchísimo, la verdad. Pero como no veo absolutamente nada de tu proyecto, pues me imagino lo que quiero un poco

Comment: Con todo ese tocho lo que quiero decir es, que si no nos enseñas qué estás haciendo no podemos saber qué está pasando. Usa el enlace [edit], enséñanos cómo está añadido al proyecto, enséñanos si hace un install correctamente (usando springboot asumo que estás haciendo un maven install antes de intentar ejecutarlo?), en fin... todos los detalles necesarios. También depende del IDE qué uses necesitarás instalar un plugin en el mismo y marcar la casilla que dice "Enable annotation processing". Enséñanos que has hecho todo eso y sigue sin funcionar, y qué error exacto te da, y podremos ayudarte!

Comment: Bienvenido, Que versión de Android Studio usas? Como instalaste Lombok?, agrega una imagen de a que te refieres con "no reconoce". Revisa [ask], saludos,